# How to make check history based on user logged in

Tags: php

i want to make order history but only the order that has been ordered by the current user that has 'logged in'..
anybody can help me?

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("authentication.php");

session_start();
$id=$_GET["id"];
$query="SELECT * FROM order_detail";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if($_SESSION["sessionusername"])
{
echo" <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table align='center' width='40%'>
<tr><td width='10%'><img src='image/banner.jpg' width='1000' height='150' alt='Master'><td></tr>                   
</table>
<table align='center' width='70%'>
<tr>
<td width='10%' align='center'><a href ='home.php'>Home</a></td><td width='15%'        align='center'><a href='aboutus.php'>About Us</a></td>
<td width='14%' align='center'><a href='news.php'>News</a></td><td width='13%'   align='center'><a href='products.php'>Products</a></td>
<td width='14%' align='center'></td>
<td width='13%' align='center'><a href='checkhistory.php'>Order History</a></td>
</tr>
</table>"; }
else
{ 
echo "<center>You Must Login First !</center>"; 
}
  ?>


<?php


while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $orderid=$data["orderid"];
$productid=$data["productid"];
$quantity=$data["quantity"];
$price=$data["price"];
$serial=$data["serial"];
$name=$data["name"];
$description=$data["description"];
?>
<table><tr><td>Order id : <?php echo $orderid ?></td>
<td>Order id : <?php echo $productid ?></td> <td>Order id : <?php echo $quantity?></td>
<td>Order id : <?php echo $price ?></td> <td>Order id : <?php echo $Serial ?></td>
<?php }?>
</tr></table>
```

i want to make order history.
which if i click order history automatically it will show the order details that have been order by the current user that has 'logged'in'

im really confused on what to do..
please helpppp !!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `WHERE user_field = :currentUserName` inside your SQL query, where `user_field` is your user identifier inside your order table, and `:currentUserName` is your current user